# assigning a Row_Number to my MySQL selection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, row-number

I have a problem of assigning a Row_Number to my MySQL selection, while ago I came across a piece of code that have proposed a solution for this situations.
I tried the code in MySQL console and it was  working well . But when I tried to use it in my PHP application as a query with PDO it returned this  `"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error"`.

The code is as following

```
SET @row_count= NULL;
SELECT ad_ID , rn from (
    select ad_ID ,@row_count :=IFNULL (@row_count,0)+1 as rn 
    from ad_table
    order by rn ) OT
WHERE rn IN (1, 10 ,20 );
```

I've checked the Databse connection and it was OK. What am I doing Wrong ?
And if it is not the suitable way of solving this problem, how can I accomplish this task??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**exec()**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) for 1st line.
ie

```
$STH = $DBH->exec('SET @row_count= NULL');
```

Then

```
$sql ="SELECT id , rn from (  select id ,@row_count :=IFNULL (@row_count,0)+1 as rn from mytable order by rn ) OT WHERE rn  IN (1, 10 ,20 )";
$STH = $DBH->query($sql);
```